# Debug.Log only once instead of as many times as there are objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 9 3d cubes. each cube has a script component, checking if the cube was touched. if so, it logs the name of the touched cube.

want: the name of the cube is logged once. reality: the name of the cube is logged 9 times (once for every cube) which makes sense .. its the same script attached to all 9 cubes. see the script below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class main: MonoBehaviour

{
    public string touchedObjectsName;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if ((Input.touchCount > 0) && (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))
        {
            Ray raycast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            RaycastHit raycastHit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit))
            {
                touchedObjectsName = raycastHit.collider.gameObject.name;
                Debug.Log(touchedObjectsName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

question: is it possible to modify the above script to log only once even if it is attached to several game objects?

thanks, dear community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you say yourself: Your script is running on all 9 cubes!

So 9 times you make a Raycast, 9 times you hit always the same object and print its name 9 times.

---

You could of course simply check if you hit yourself:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit))
{
    // only do it if the hit object is the same as this script is attached to
    if(raycastHit.gameObject == gameObject)
    {
        touchedObjectsName = raycastHit.collider.gameObject.name;
        Debug.Log(touchedObjectsName);
    }
}
```

But that's very redundant => unefficient!

Rather only have this script running somewhere in your scene **once** as it can already track **any** touched object so there is no need to run it multiple times.

Comment: thanks! 

looks like i was standing on the hose there (as the germans say) ... for some reason i assumed the script needs to be attached to the game object i want to check/ray cast to.

removed the script form the cubes and attached it to the main cam, works as wanted now.